# How to escape characters for a Google Sitelinks search box in Razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

How can I output the script below correctly using the Razor engine?  I've tried every way I know to escape the " and the @ but can't get it to work without an error.

This is the line that is giving me problems:

```
"@context": "http://schema.org",
```

Here is the full script, as provided by google:

```js
< script type = "application/ld+json" > {
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebSite",
  "url": "https://www.example-petstore.com/",
  "potentialAction": {
    "@type": "SearchAction",
    "target": "https://query.example-petstore.com/search?q={search_term_string}",
    "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
  }
} < /script>
```

[google sitelinks search box script](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/slsb-overview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use double @@ and see if that works

`"@@context": "http://schema.org",`

Comment: that's it!  I had the double @ before the quotes and couldn't get that to work.  Much thanks